# Cannot publish an ASP. Net application using Visual Studio as I cannot find password in website summary page on Somee.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to publish an ASP.Net web application using Visual Studio. While I am trying to publish using Visual Studio, VS is asking user id, password, and other details. I can find other details on the Website Summary page on Somee.com. I cannot find the password on that page. It says "Use the password from this control panel". What does that mean? I used my Somee.com account's password. But it is not able to connect in Visual Studio. I can add and publish the same using Somee's control panel, but I want to be able to publish through Visual Studio for seamless deployment.

By the way, I can add the website manually using Somee's File Manager, and the website is working properly. There's just a problem publishing using Visual Studio. Any solution would be much appreciated.

**Here's the control panel which shows website details. Password is highlighted in Yellow Rectangle**:
[image]

**Here's the Visual Studio error**:
[image]

Comment: Well, can you connect using FTP? Does FTP work from say using the windows explorer? I mean, if FTP don't work from windows, it sure not going to work from VS

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, How to make it work? when I try with the FTP URL specified in the control panel, using Windows File Explorer or a browser, it didn't work, Previously, it used to work by directly publishing through Visual Studio. But since Somee changed its UI, it is not working. ie, I am not able to find the password to connect.

Comment: Well, you simple need a working FTP password. I mean, you hit windows button, then E, and you get a file explorer. In the address bar of the file explore, type in "ftp:// // //your site name. You get a prompt for user + password. Once you done this, then of course using the windows file explore will look like any folder you browse, but your browsing the server files and folders. If you can't get a basic FTP connection working, then ZERO use to try and use VS to publish then, right? So, you have to get a valid user and logon. We the public have ZERO clue as to what your user and password is.